# Validar datos alfabéticos y espacios con Laravel por el lado del servidor

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

¿Cómo validar un formulario para que acepte datos alfabéticos y con espacios?

Por ejemplo: estaba usando **alpha**, eso sí me funciona cuando pongo solo una palabra, pero si quiero poner la frase *Hola mundo*, no me deja porque no reconoce los espacios

Sé que se puede hacer con HTML5, con el atributo **pattern** pero lo que quiero es hacerlo por el lado del servidor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No existe una validación incluida que permita caracteres alfabéticos y espacios, para eso tocaría usar un regex o crear un validador personalizado.

Asumo que lo más fácil sería una expresión regular, en este caso sería algo así:

```
regex:/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/u
```

En caso que desees un validador personalizado, la documentación de Laravel lo explica detalladamente: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: Muchas gracias, eso es lo que buscaba :)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel cuenta con su propio validador, en la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation) lo encuentras explicado a detalle, aquí te dejo un ejemplo:

```
 //En tu controlador
 $validador = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'variablePost1' => 'required|string',
    ]);

    if ($validador->fails()) {
        return redirect('post/create')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    }
//codigo a ejecutar si la variable cumple con los requisitos
```

Con este código validas la variable `variablePost1` que se envía por tu formulario, esta debe ser `requerida` y de tipo `string`, te repito en la documentación puedes ver las diferentes formas de validar en `Laravel` y, por supuesto, los diferentes tipos de `validadores` (que son muchos).

La validación de `Laravel` es más compleja de lo que expuse aquí, puedes poner reglas especificas a cada campo así como sus mensajes de error e incluso puedes modificar el nombre del campo al mostrar errores (muchas veces enviamos el valor como `txtValor`, podemos cambiar ese nombre y mostrarlo como "Cadena" o lo que se acople a tu proyecto).

Como no vemos tu código, solo puse un ejemplo genérico, si modificas tu pregunta con parte de tu código puedo modificar mi respuesta para que sea mas certera.

Comment: ¿Esto qué aporta? la pregunta es muy específica.

Comment: Aporta que el OP menciona Laravel y, notoriamente, no conoce esa función del Framework, se le enseña la documentación para que lo conozca y use, así mismo un pequeño ejemplo de como usarlo, ¿De que sirve trabajar con un Framework sin usar su potencial? __Un Framework nos evita tener que programar estas partes (en este caso un validación básica), de esta manera nos resulta más fácil centrarnos en programar la aplicación.__

Comment: Por favor lee las preguntas primero, el op SÍ conoce esa función, simplemente no encuentra como validar cierto tipo de información.

Comment: Por favor lee el título y las etiquetas de las pregunta. El OP conoce funciones de PHP, no de Laravel.

Comment: ¿Qué tiene que ver alpha y pattern con php? la primera es una regla de validación de Laravel https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-alpha y la otra es de HTML. Bienvenido a StackOverflow.

Comment: Tienes razón en cuanto la pattern, entendí que lo quería usar con PHP del lado del servidor, pero le da más aporte a mi respuesta puesto que no es necesario usar regex para validar un simple cadena con espacios, para eso está string.

Comment: Por favor lee la pregunta... y analiza lo que quiere el OP, voy a editar la pregunta, tal vez entiendas mejor así.

Comment: EmmanuelHD disculpa tal vez no me supe explicar bien, se que puedo usar 'String' pero lo que yo quería es solo datos alfabéticos por eso encontre 'alpha' pero ese no me acepta espacios y de ahí surgió mi pregunta